# In a matrix ring, no zero divisors may have an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

In a general ring with 1, a right (left) zero divisor cannot have a right (left) inverse. In a matrix ring over a field, a stronger condition is satisfied: a (right or left) zero divisor cannot have a (right or left) inverse, with the proof I know invoking the rank plus nullity theorem (which makes sense, because infinite dimensional linear transformations can have right-inverses and be right-zero divisors). Is this more or less a peculiarity of matrices, or am I missing a more general property that they (and perhaps other spaces) possess?

Comment: I don't understand the *However* in the second sentence...

Comment: Edited...I meant to indicate matrix rings satisfy a stronger condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm glad to see that Dedekind finite rings have been raised as the right concept to look at, but I think a little more can be done to help you see where the condition lies with respect to other conditions you might know.

Here is a diagram reproduced from a portion of my notes that gives a view (at least a partial one):

[image]

There are a lot of strange names up there, but between Lam's two books (*First course on noncommutative rings* and *Lectures on modules and rings*) you would be able to reproduce this table. In addition to those books, there is an additional paper by Lam that talks about stable range and its immediate relatives: [*A crash course on...*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.berkeley.edu%2F~lam%2Fohio.ps&ei=o86gUZfJLePI0QHam4HoCA&usg=AFQjCNH6h3TAdkZWey10LzTAKcDu0cdprg&sig2=EQcFL2cPpYDOGXiWAxx1Xg)

Of course, matrix rings over division rings lie in the "semisimple" box. In addition to the Dedekind finite box, I think you should also know about "stably finite". A ring $R$ is said to be stably finite if all of the $n\times n$ matrix rings over $R$ are Dedekind finite.

Since Noetherian and perfect rings have already been mentioned, I'd like to contribute by pointing out two "new" examples given here. Since there are two-sided self-injective rings which aren't Noetherian and aren't semiperfect, and unit regular rings which aren't Noetherian and aren't semiperfect, nor injective on both sides, I think both of those classes of rings are "new" to this post.

Finally, there is one thing to add to this diagram. I don't normally keep a box for "commutative ring," but if it were in this picture, it would have an arrow pointing to "Stably finite."

---

There is one more condition which might interest you. A ring in which every element which *isn't* a left zero divisor is a unit is called a **right cohopfian ring**. This means essentially that if multiplication by an element on the left makes an injective map $R\to R$, then it is an isomorphism. This relates closely to an alternative definition of Dedekind finite: If multiplication on the left by $a$ is *surjective* then it is an isomorphism. This is saying that $R$ is "hopfian". It turns out that for a ring, this condition is left-right symmetric, but the cohopfian version isn't :)

I've got a bit of info on them in this solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135051/29335 . One-sided cohofian rings are also Dedekind finite. I would have to double check which things on the graph point to "cohopfian" :) They're a bit of an oddball...

Comment: "FUD" stands for "finite uniform dimension," and "strongly pi-regular" is this: every chain of ideals of the form $aR\supseteq a^2R\supseteq\dots$ stabilizes. It turns out that the definition is equivalent to the left-hand version. From this, it's easy to see that left perfect rings and right perfect rings are strongly pi regular.

Comment: Good lord that's a lot of definitions. My head hurts. +1 for the diagram!

Comment: @Steve I didn't expect you to know even half of them, but in the future you might enjoy looking back onthe diagram :) Hang on, I'm adding one more...

Comment: I (and I think most people who occasionally do algebra) know 5 to 7 of these boxes by heart. Where are Frobenius rings?

Comment: @Steve I really think you might be interested in Cohopfian rings, those are closely related. Quasi-Frobenius rings are really interesting! They are exactly the Artinian self-injective rings. Examples: $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for $n>1$, any group algebra over a field and finite group, the exterior algebra of a finite dimensional vector space. Frobenius rings are slightly more special, but I'll forgo defining them and just say that semisimple rings and commutative QF rings are all Frobenius.

Comment: @Steve I would have a hard time remembering these if I hadn't sat down and sketched out "maps" like these.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite a bit more general than just matrix rings, though obviously *some* finiteness condition is required. It's a property of (left) *Noetherian* rings that anything that has a left inverse also has a right inverse.

Proof: if $x \in R$ has a left inverse $x^{-1}$, then right multiplication by $x$ is surjective since $y=(yx^{-1})x$. It is also injective: let $I_n$ be the (left ideal) kernel of right multiplication by $x^n$, and choose $n$ with $I_n=I_{n+1}$ (Noether used here). Then if $y \in I_1$, we can write $y=z x^n$ for some $z$, so we have $$0=y x=zx^{n+1} \quad \implies \quad 0=zx^n=y$$ by choice of $n$. Thus right multiplication by $x$ is also injective. Hence
$$0=(1-x x^{-1})x \implies 1=x x^{-1}$$ so $x^{-1}$ is a right inverse for $x$.

PS: If the ring is *right Noetherian*, then one applies the opposite argument (interchanging right and left) to the element $x^{-1}$ to show that it also has a left inverse. So being Noetherian on one side is enough.

Answer (score 5):

It is a peculiarity of “vaguely finite” rings.

A [right Artinian ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring) has an even stronger property shared by matrices: if $a$ is not a left zero-divisor (there is no nonzero $b$ with $ab=0$), then $a$ has both a left and right inverse (and so they are equal). Indeed, it need only have the DCC on principal right ideals, a so-called [left perfect ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring).

The exact rings you are looking for are the “Dedekind-finite” rings: those rings in which $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$. Every [one-sided noetherian ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring) is Dedekind finite.

One also has in general, that if $ab=1$ then $a(ba-1) = aba-a = 0$ so that if $a$ has a right inverse, then either it is a unit (has a left inverse identical to its right inverse) or it is a left zero divisor.

If $ab=1$, but $ba\neq 1$, then notice that $a \cdot \left((1-ba)a^j +b\right) = 0 + ab = 1$ and that for distinct $i,j$, $(1-ba)a^i \neq (1-ba)a^j$, so that if $a$ has a right inverse, but no left inverse, then it must have infinitely many right inverses.

*Proof of equivalence:* Suppose no one-sided zero-divisor can have a one-sided inverse. Then every element with a one-sided inverse must have a two-sided inverse, but that is precisely the condition that $ab=1 \implies ba=1$, that is, the ring is Dedekind-finite. Conversely suppose that the ring is Dedekind-finite: then any element with a one-sided inverse has a two-sided inverse, and so cannot be a zero divisor.

One can find this and more in Lam's First Course on Non-commutative Rings, especially chapter 1.

Comment: Nice, +1. I know I should read Lam's books, but I have never gotten around to it...