# Rings in which left regular elements are right regular

Tags: ring-theory

Is there a characterization of those rings in which every left regular element is right regular?

Comment: In a right Noetherian semiprime ring, any left regular element is right regular.

Comment: @Sanath- Thanks for the comment. I am aware of that situation, but I was hoping for necessary and sufficient conditions on a ring, if any are known, for left regulars to be right regulars.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/134108/29335

Comment: I don't think I've heard a characterization. This condition is very delicate.

One broad sufficient condition is for the ring to be **left cohopfian**, which means left regular elements are units.

Comment: @rscweib- Thanks for the info. I had never seen a characterization either and was wondering if someone else had.